# Paypal: How to display payer's email on the thank you page?

Tags: php, email, paypal

I know that this isn't a new topic. However, I couldn't find an answer to it.

I have read some information on Paypal Developer and PDT/IPN...etc. I understand we need to verify the TX transaction ID (Success) before GET the information from it.

Basically, once we have created a button, buyer completes a purchase, Paypal redirects the buyer back to our website (assuming I have turned on all the PDT and other settings), then how can I retrieve the buyer's email? How can I display the buyer's email on the thank you page? Thank you for the purchase. An email has been sent to xxx @ example.com

Is the coding at this page still relevant (update to date)
[PayPal: pass the email address to the return/"thank you" page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960365/paypal-pass-the-email-address-to-the-return-thank-you-page)

Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9960365/paypal-pass-the-email-address-to-the-return-thank-you-page) for PDT, so that you will get the buyer email address in the PDT response. Enable PDT at your PayPal account. You can use PayPal IPN as well for getting the buyer email address.